# What is the Constable Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

The description says "Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation". I do not know what the phrase "pro-tem" means. In what situation would this even occur? Does it warrant a badge? I feel that it is akin to Area 51. It wouldn't occur nearly enough to warrant having a badge.

Also: The Sheriff badge description ends with a period. No other description has ending punctuation. The badge-earners page has two periods now. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff `at least 1 year..`

Comment: Pro-Tem (pro tempore), in a non-SO context at least, is a temporary fill-in typically for a leader, such as the President Pro-tem of the US senate who fills in for the VP (who is the nominal leader of the Senate, with duties related to running sessions, and may cast tiebreaking votes) when needed.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/. Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/192187

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has been awarded that badge

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A pro-tem moderator is someone assigned to the role by Stack Exchange until an election can take place. This is the usual procedure for new beta sites, where the community is still forming.

[*pro-tem*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro_tem) literally means "for the time being".

The badge is one of honour; those who received one were there in the beginning and carried the burden of moderation until the site and its community was mature enough to carry on on its own.

See [Moderator Pro-tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) on the Stack Exchange blog.

Comment: So that means there is no hope that anyone will be earning this badge. Right?

Comment: Not on already established sites, no.

Comment: I understood the first part when I read the description, but what I did not understand is " or through site graduation". How does that part work, please?

Comment: @PhishMaster: if the site graduates (and so will hold elections for moderators), the pro-tem moderators get the badge, even if they have been a pro-tem moderator for less than a year.

Comment: Thank you, but graduates from what to what? Beta to permanent?

Comment: @PhishMaster: that's all becoming a little more complicated, it used to be a black-and-white beta-to-graduated flick of a switch, but see [Let's break up with "Graduation" and remove a bunch of "Beta" labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727)