# Does it makes sense to have the same graduation criteria for all beta sites?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, graduating-sites, site-stats

Different SE sites cover a wide range of topics. And the thought process in generating a question is VERY different from one to another. In programming related sites, I can come up with many question in a day just because I run into errors. Those can be very specific to my case, therefore been less likely that I'll find an answer already there.
In software use related sites, a new software or version show up very often creating a whole new set of associated questions.

In the other hand, in Earths Sciences, the SE community I'm more active in. New fields of research don't appear very often, the thought process to come up with a question is much longer and questions don't tend to be that specific, so you are more likely to find the answer already somewhere on the internet.

As a consequence, Earths Sciences beta duplicates or triplicates graduation requirements when it comes to avid users or visits, but it does very bad when it comes to the average number of questions per day.

[image]

Given all the above: **Does it really makes sense to have fix minimum requirements for all beta sites?**

Also, similar differences can explain why some sites will have more answers per questions than others.

Comment: See also [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). I'm also hoping we can [break up with “Graduation”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307988/1438) over time.

Comment: Writing is also doing very well on all stats except QPD and has [strong community support to advance](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1478/1993).  We've been in "beta" for 7 years; we're probably never going to hit 10 QPD but our quality and all other metrics are very good.  I'm sure there are lots of other sites like these two.

Comment: [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com) is just like Writing. [Area 51 shows](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) that gets over 13,000 visits per day, has nearly 1,000 users with 200+ rep, and yet is still "beta" after 7 years because it hasn't hit that arbitrary 10 questions per day threshold.

Comment: Yes, the criteria should be defined according to the category (more precisely programming vs non-programming) at Area5.

Answer (score 1):

I have participated in the Betas of two sites that I moderate:

- [GIS](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems), as a normal user, and saw it graduate quickly 7 years ago

[image]

- [Genealogy & Family History](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history), as a moderator for the second half of its 5 years

[image]

At G&FH SE we struggle with question volume far more than your site but nevertheless I think that all sites should be subject to the same measures.

If one or more measures were found to be too hard or too easy for sites to reach and were changed as a result, *for all sites*, then I would not object, but I think it is important that all sites are judged equally for graduation-readiness.

I would also not object to a rule that says perhaps "4 greens and an amber" is enough to graduate.

Comment: This is a good example of what I mean. I also participate in GIS, and most of the questions are related to software, scripting and coding. That are topics that naturally generate lots of questions. But if you count the non-software related GIS  question the number of questions per day would be much lower.

Comment: @CamiloRada Genealogy & Family History is a topic which I think should generate many more questions than GIS but it is an ongoing challenge to train users in how to ask right-sized single focused questions.