# It is now all but impossible to tell sites apart at a glance

Tags: feature-request, design

Let's play a little guessing game. I came across an open tab -- which site am I on?

[image]

All but impossible to tell at a glance from design elements alone!¹  All my subconscious has to go on are differences in highlight colors, which may or may not be unique in the set of sites I frequently visit, and which I may or may not be able to perceive accurately.

To me, this is a consequence of aligning themes *too much*. Note that this is not about emotions like "feeling at home" on "my" site -- that exists and is affected, too -- but a plain usability flaw.

It is important that we are able to immediatley/intuitively tell different (graduated) SE sites apart. Please re-introduce visual hints to that effect.

Candidates:

- custom badge icons (still exist on some sites)
- custom voting/favorite/accept icons
- a small version of the site logo at the top of the left-bar menu
- a small version of the site log in the top bar, replacing the SE logo
- background art
- keep a shrunken version of the site banner around²

---

1. Yes, I blurred out text, including the site name in the search bar. It's low-contrast and out of the way (absent, even, for users who disable top-bar stickiness). *Yes*, it's possible to determine the page by scrolling up or down, reading things, or tracking down the favicon in a potentially full tab bar. That's not the point -- the point is whether I can tell where I am just by seeing an arbitrary part of a Q&A page.
2. This seems to be a common idea for reactive designs.

Comment: Yes, if you cover up every reference to what site you are on, you can't tell what site you are on! I do think you have a point here but to me, you had to try so hard and blank half the page out to get you point across. Yes, I think the sites should get their individuality back but no, I do not  think "It is now all but impossible to tell which site you're on" and your image proves it.

Comment: You conveniently cut out the part of the screenshot that *lists the name of the site that you're on*, which is rather disingenuous when it comes to ones ability to determine what site you're on.

Comment: This is Tex.  you scrolled down a bit and blurred out the "Search Tex-LaTex". You can easily find out what site you're on by just scrolling up or looking at the search bar, or the colour-theme, or the favicon.  Oh, but this is a hypothetical question, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkKirby The _only_ reference to the site is the one in the search box, which is low-contrast, has to be _read_ (as opposed to seen/perceived), and is something I never look at.

Comment: @Snow I might find a tab in any state, for instance scrolled to some answer. The scenario I captured is not artificial. Having to scroll to tell where I am is horrible UX.

Comment: Favicon is a fair point, but is not visually "there" as much when you have 15+ tabs open.

Comment: @Raphael But you don't need to scroll.  You just need to look at the URL of the site.  You just don't want to, for some reason you haven't stated.

Comment: @MarkKirby Obviously, you should only look at sites that have received the new, more unified design. Unique badges seem to stay, but don't exist for all sites (note e.g. how tex.SE has the default badges).

Comment: That is my bad on the badges, that site does have the old theme. I still think you tried too hard to get your point across though

Comment: @Raphael: So, the text in the search bar is too low-contrast, but icons on badges and small per-site icons, those are more easily visible? I don't really see that. Why is it important for site recognition to be due to an image?

Comment: @MarkKirby Maybe. I was trying to destill out some of the considerable unease (and rage, see e.g. [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781/3213)) caused by the new design. This here is one thing I stumbled over myself, and could be fixed by doing some of the things the community has been asking for since the new design was first proposed.

Comment: @NicolBolas The icons appear in the main content area, which is where my eyes are supposed to be. (Actually testing this with a little game would be interesting. Which design elements support distinguishing sites most quickly? I can only guess.)

Comment: @Raphael: If you are wondering which site you're on, why would your eyes still be in the main content area? If I'm confused as to which site I'm on, I'd start by looking at the top bar. Remember: most of the time, you know which site you're on or you can easily tell from the actual *content*. We don't need some huge thing constantly poking you in the eye to remind you of something you probably already know.

Comment: A good example to check out may be [ubuntu.SE] vs [unix.SE]. Similar content here (I might have searched on both sites for the same issue), so it's all the more important to know where you are (e.g. for commenting with the correct link)! Scrolled to the middle of a longer page, all we have to go on is the different highlight color (orange vs blue) and the different grid size in the background (both are a simple pattern!). Interestingly, this seems to be enough for me, but it _could_ be clearer.

Comment: I was able to spot TeX.sx because I know that avatar: it is our resident killer bunny! `:)` *Edit:* `+1`

Comment: @Servy In my Firefox there is no URL-bar if I don't mouse over the tab bar. So no, it is not necessarily there all the time (what a waste of screen real estate that would be!).

Comment: @Skillmon Why go out of your way to hide the URL bar and then get upset when you can't tell what site you're on because you can't see the URL?

Comment: @Servy because I'm used to visit sites which I can distinguish from each other on first look (*without reading anything*). I have >200 tabs open and on above 90% I can instantly tell you what they are related to. There is no need for that bar. The only reason I keep it is the widgets of addons (and the fact that some of them don't work with a fully disabled URL bar). My Firefox should be centred on usability for me as a power-user and not on clicky-pointy usage. The design choices made on SE are poorly and a distinguishable design shouldn't be dropped, imho.

Comment: @Servy There is a reason why the TeX.SX community is posting css user scripts to restore a better design at their main site.

Answer (score 10):

There have been past (declined) requests to put the site logo/name in the top bar, because SE wants the network brand identity there.  However, your suggestion to put it into the left nav makes a lot of sense.  I think we want the site name/logo, not just the small logo -- you've got the whole width of the left bar to work with, so it'd fit.  For comparison, here is what a publication-specific menu (the equivalent of our left nav) looks like on Medium, the site that SE recommends for per-site blogs:

[image: Worldbuilding blog menu on Medium]

Notice the simplified logo (no background) and the use of background color.  If that top bar were sticky, the control were a generic hamburger, and I were scrolled farther down the page, I'd still be able to tell what site I'm on.

Putting the site name/logo at the top of the left nav would look a little odd *when at the top of the page*, but would be informative everywhere else.  I'm not a designer, but it feels to me like people with more sense of design could solve that problem somehow.

*Maybe* it makes sense to instead replace the hamburger control with the site logo (sort of like what Medium does), but that'd require more thought and probably some testing.  For better or worse, people know that the current hamburger control means "click me to toggle some sort of menu"; a ringed planet or an ampersand or a small tree doesn't convey that message so easily.

Comment: "Putting the site name/logo at the top of the left nav would look a little odd when at the top of the page, but would be informative everywhere else." -- I imagine the "main" logo could "move" (and shrink) to the left menu when the user scrolls down. That is, no double-logo when at the top.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I immediately thought TeX/LaTeX. The color scheme was the tipoff.

> It is important that we are able to immediately/intuitively tell different (graduated) SE sites apart.

This seems to be the crux of the argument and I have two concerns:

1. I can guess why that's important to you, but it's just asserted in the question. What value does having more customizations provide other than duplicating what was lost with the new design? (I'm not trying to be obstinate here, I want to have some more input so I can advocate for you. See also: [What does constructive criticism of a design change look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like))
2. Right now graduated sites are [mostly](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/puzzlings-new-favicon-is-too-similar-to-workplaces-favicon) different, but all of the beta sites are identical except for flavicon and title. I'd [dearly love to change that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307988/1438), but it's not possible until we implement some sort of flexible (and disciplined) customization framework. Since a major goal of this project is to build that framework, it seems like special pleading to exclude "beta" sites.

When you put the two points together, it also occurs to me that users of several beta sites have had to live with this situation for a while. (This was me a few years ago.) I sympathize with sites that have lost unique design elements. But I don't know what to make of an argument that accentuates the existing graduate/beta divide. Am I misunderstanding the situation?

Comment: "For what it's worth, I immediately thought TeX/LaTeX. The color scheme was the tipoff." -- If colors work for you, sure. About 10% of all males (far fewer females) have some issue with perceiving colors. Also, I can't say I have a good overview over all SE sites. I suspect that, for instance, [rpg.SE] might come close [tex.SE] after migration to the new framework. I don't think balancing 170+ (and growing) color pallettes for distinguishability is an enjoyable or even feasible task.

Comment: ad 2: Sure, and I'm fully on board with that idea! Note that some of the ideas I list work to distinguish beta sites as well, such as including name/logo in the left menu. One could also imagine including the name in the background (maybe sticking to the bottom) in some way. Or, I don't know, have betas come up with their own logo? Anyway, if the plan is to add distinguishing features to betas earlier with the new concept, isn't the point moot?

Comment: I for one have always disliked the generic look. It never felt like you _got_ somewhere. Much like visiting a historic city center vs a generic mall. Sure, you get ice cream in both places, but there is a very big difference. I hope the new framework will end up being more like Roman-designed city centers (same principles, but aged to individual flair) instead of malls with different colors and plants in the same pots.

Comment: Oh, metaphor mode engaged. Not knowing which SE site you're on is similar to stepping out of a subway and not immediately knowing which station you're in/on.

Comment: ad 1: Not being a designer myself, I don't have the vocabulary to objectively reason for why different websites should look differently in the browser. So lets call it a subjective requirement and note that some people seem to agree, while others disagree. That said, bringing back some customizations is _one_ way to go (but may be more important for the "feel-good" aspects which are not really the point in this discussion, despite me getting on the metaphor train).