# Inconsistency in image posting between mobile & desktop, mobile is better

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-interface, mobile-web, editor

When adding an image to a post from the mobile site, the "inline" markdown form:

```
[![alt](url)]
```

is used. This is clean, self-contained, and easy to edit. The desktop site, however, adds the image in the "reference" form:

```
[![alt][n]][n]
```

with a reference at the end of the post:

```
[n]: url
```

(I'm not even sure why `[n]` is repeated in the reference; it doesn't seem to be correct Markdown.)

The inline/non-reference form it clearly preferable from a standpoint of locality and easy editing. And if you edit the same post from both - often I have some of the pics I want to include in a post on my phone, so I write the original question or answer on desktop, then quickly edit it from my phone to add more pics - the inconsistency is really messy.

Please make it so that the desktop site behaves consistently with the mobile one and always uses the inline form.

Comment: It's a link and allows you to easily change where the image links to. By default, it opens the image but I often make the image smaller in the post and link to a full-sized image. But you can also link to the image source website instead. I find it pretty useful.

Comment: @Catija: Is your comment referring to the extra `[n]` at the end? It should be possible to do that with the inline form too, no?

Comment: You need two urls to have different image vs link target. You change [n] to [n+1] and... ta-da! The point is, I don't have to remember the correct change to markdown because it's already there.

Comment: For an example, see the image in my question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727/284336 the markdown is `[![Screenshot of a part of the full sites list.][14]][15]`